# Inability to use `IMPORTHTML` in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I use the website below:

http://score.nowscore.com/odds/match.aspx?id=1396936

to import data from that website to Google sheets but it does NOT work. The formula I use to try to import data is:

```
 =IMPORTHTML("http://score.nowscore.com/odds/match.aspx?id=1396936","table")
```

Comment: Write a script that scrapes that website and acts as a proxy. That should be pretty easy to do

Answer (score 4):

The error shown by Google Sheets is

```
#N/A Could not fetch url
```

which means the problem is that the Google bot cannot access the page. Usually this happens because the server's owners block bots/scrapers from reading their content. A look at [their robots.txt file](http://www.nowscore.com/robots.txt) confirms the guess:

```
User-agent: * 
.....
Disallow: /Odds
```

So, all robots are blocked from viewing /Odds (and many other pages of that site). Nothing you can do about that.