# My ImportXML with XPath doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, xpath

I've got a problem. I'm trying to import data in my google sheet document using =ImportXML with XPath from this page : https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/produits-de-bourse/cours/warrants/2rPDE000HV19H99

What i want is to pick up the 1st value which is right bellow this : FB/UCB WT 18

So by inspecting the page with Google Chrome, i find the right line and copy its XPath. It gives me that :

```
//*[@id="main-content"]/div/section/header/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]
```

I go on my Google Sheet document, 
write this :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/produits-de-bourse/cours/warrants/2rPDE000HV19H99";J57)
```

With inside J57 this :

`//*[@id="main-content"]/div/section/header/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]`

But i'm getting no value :

```
#N/A
```

I need your help to fix the XPath problem, i don't know at all what's wrong with it, it is really annoying...

And asweel i'd like to know how to put put the XPath directly inside the command: i can't because of the " .

Thanks a lot.

[image: My Google Sheet document]

Comment: Related: [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the reference value ( FB/UCB WT 18) isn't included anymore on the source web page.