# Syntax problem in ImportXML function

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

This is related to an earlier question regarding syntax issues with ImportXML function in Google Sheets relating to data from this providers web site:

https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_au/N

The above link seems to be a simpler layout of the data needed.

The data needed is the Q32018 'previous close' figure of "90.85".  The element is:

```
<td class="settle">90.85</td>
```

The syntax below does not work even though the path was taken using Chrome Dev Tools with an XPath copy.

```
//*[@id="dataset"]/div/div/table/tbody[2]/tr[1]/td[13]
```

The full syntax used:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.asxenergy.com.au/futures_au/N",
 "//*[@id="dataset"]/div/div/table/tr[1]/td[13]")
```

I have tried shorter pathways but I cannot resolve the issue.  I have also tried multiple versions of the data on other pages by the provider but with no success.  It may be that the provider has somehow blocked access and if so let me know if I should just give up.

Comment: just a pointer: you need to use `'` in `" "`

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML is only able to get the xPath nodes that are included on the webpage source code. Unfortunately the node that you are looking for isn't included.

Related

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)