# Google Spreadsheet IMPORTXML problem to extract from a web page

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, xpath, xml

I'm trying to extract the "Comestibilité" and "Remarques" parts from a page using IMPORTXML in my Google Spreadsheet but I just can't get to them, they are generated by JavaScript but I cannot figure out how get those tags in IMPORTXML results. Any idea how?

I read many posts and tried :

```
 =IMPORTXML("https://www.mycoquebec.org/bas.php?tag=Baorangia%20bicolor", "//*")
 =IMPORTXML("https://www.mycoquebec.org/bas.php?tag=Baorangia%20bicolor", "//script")
```

But even if I get many results, I do not get the tags I'm looking for !!?

I also tried:

```
 =IMPORTXML("https://www.mycoquebec.org/bas.php?tag=Baorangia%20bicolor", "//*[@id='Comestibilité']")
```

Wich returns no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheets built-in funcion IMPORTXML can't access tags created by JavaScript. You could ask for a software recommendation on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or look for related web scrapping 
 programming questions on https://stackoverflow.com.

Related:

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Comment: Thanks Rubén, I resolved using the Chrome extension Web Scraper.