# Retrieve fund price from Vanguard website using importxml in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml, importhtml

This was working in Google Sheets but now I get `#N/A` message:

> Imported Content is Empty

A1: `https://institutional.vanguard.com/web/c1/product-details/fund/1680`
A2: `//*[@id='dailyNavValue']`
A3: `uimportxml(A1, A3)` which results in: `#N/A Imported Content is Empty`.

I just want to retrieve the mutual fund price.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163

Answer (score 0):

The site you are requesting runs completely on JavaScript, therefore it's not possible to import it into Google Sheets. All you can get is:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://institutional.vanguard.com/web/c1/product-details/fund/1680", "//*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`=importXML("https://personal.vanguard.com/us/JSP/Funds/VGITab/VGIFundPricePerfTabContent.jsf?FundIntExt=INT&FundId=3346","//*[@id='currentQuoteForm:priceTabletbody0']/tr[1]/td[2]")`

You will need the Vanguard fund ID number.

Comment: Welcome to [webpps.se]. Please add a brief explanation about why your formula is using a different URL that the one used in the question.

Comment: The URL is from Vanguard's personal investor web site.  I got it from another web source. It works much better for mutual fund prices than Google Finance.The fund number 3346 is for Vanguard S&P 600 Small Cap Value Index ETF. All Vanguard funds and ETFs have distinct ID numbers that you need to retrieve data.