# IMPORTHTML - Can't find specific table on WNBA.com

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, importhtml

https://www.wnba.com/stats/team-stats-advanced/#?Season=2018
 
Is the web page. I can't seem to find the table for advanced team rates or opponent.

Answer (score 0):

The site you are trying to scrape is under JavaScript control, therefore can't be imported into Google Sheets. You will need to find your data on some different website.

[image: 0]

Comment: https://www.basketball-reference.com/wnba/years/2018.html    What about basketball reference?

Comment: possible but only what you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwlVc.png

Comment: Unfortunate, thanks for the info though. One last question, how can I tell which sites I can pull data from and which I can't?

Comment: you can tell immediately just by disabling JS - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126329/186471