# Trying to use Google Sheets importHTML() to import a table. But no content appears

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, html, importhtml

I'm attempting to load the following website into Google Sheets:

https://www.lasvegasadvisor.com/vegas-lines/?sport=ncaafb&period=0

Can anyone help provide a formula that would work in google docs to get this done? This website is updated at random times throughout the day so I want to use google docs to help track that.

I've included two images below of what I currently am doing. Any help/insight is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks,

'[image: NCAAF Data]

[image: NCAAF Formula]strong text

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search / research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Related: [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Comment: **How** are you *attempting to load the following website*? Show us.

Comment: Hi Jan, I just added some pictures of what I currently am doing. I have done this in the past for other websites that have worked which is why I'm confused. Maybe it's the type of website? None the less any insight would be sooo hopeful!

Answer (score 1):

`IMPORTHTML` doesn't works because the page you are trying to scrape use JavaScript to add the data tables to the page. Google Sheets doesn't have built-in functions that are able to scrape data that is isn't included on the source code.

Related

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)