# Google Sheets: word count for a webpage content (url) for SEO

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

For SEO analysis, I am using Google Sheets to extract basic data from my own webpages.

I am able to access page title, description, `<h1>` tags, or number of characters via `LEN()`:

```
=IMPORTXML(A3, "//title/text()")
=IMPORTXML(A3, "//meta[@name='description']/@content")
=IMPORTXML(A3, "//h1")
```

However, I cannot find a way to count the number of words in `<body>` (excluding html tags). I am trying to identify pages with thin content for SEO.

Comment: There aren't enough details. It's worth to note that IMPORTXML can't see the elements added dynamically. Related: [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Answer (score 0):

```
=importxml(A4,"//div[@class='entry-content clr']")
```

'entry-content clr' is the part of the page that contains main content in my WP theme.