# Extracting Titles to Sheets By Scraping

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to write a formula that will scrape all of the titles of products from this page:
https://www.1stdibs.com/fashion/

what am I doing wrong?

=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.1stdibs.com/fashion/")
 , 10000, 1), "where Col1 contains 'https://www.1stdibs.com/product' offset 1", 0), 
 "href=""(.+)"" “))

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what you are doing wrong, if your formula isn't working and you don't know why, you could check each part of it to find where is the problem.

Maybe you should start by validating that `IMPORTDATA` is the correct function by reading:

1. the corresponding help article in https://support.google.com/docs
2. [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Comment: =IMPORTXML("https://www.1stdibs.com/dealers/la-maison-moderne/shop/","//class//a[@data-tn='portfolio-row-product-name')") currently isnt working and I am not sure why.....

Comment: @aud1one Have you read the number 2 link ?