# Google Sheets ImportXML //div[@class= is not working

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I am trying to scrape the div "tech-name" from this website

https://www.whatruns.com/website/bestbuy.com

with the following formula

=index(importxml("https://www.whatruns.com/website/bestbuy.com","//div[@class='tech-name']"),1)

but I cannot figure it out why it says

Imported content is empty.

Comment: Welcome. Please read https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163 and tell us if the data that you want to retrieve is show when you access the webpage with JavaScript disabled in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `=Importdata()`

It'll import html :

[image]

As I searched through the results I realised one of the row contains names of tech you are (i suppose) looking for. I used a regexmatch and some filter to come up with a list (not clean). 
[image]

Here are a few things that might unlock your case.

[Sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k0iCl3ZOQWwy2ZjMdQb45Ov2CADZuf9mNUUAsTdUz5I/edit#gid=0)