# IMPORTHTML - unable to import table

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I try to import on my sheets a table o this url
http://travian.kirilloid.ru/build.php#b=18&mb=1&s=1.45

I use this sintaxis:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://travian.kirilloid.ru/build.php#b=18&mb=1&s=1.45";"table";1)
```

What is the error?

Comment: Welcome. It is a table and not a list. Even so. Unfortunately you cannot import it because it is generated using some javascript.

Comment: Related [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTHTML is only able to import data from a well formed web page that include on its source code the table to be imported a HTML tags (table, thead, tbody, tr, th, td) but the table is populate by using JavaScript.

First you should do a further analysis of the page. To do this will need to learn about HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

Related

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)