# Is it possible to import data into Google Sheets that is in a <div>?

Tags: google-sheets, import, html

I've been using `=ImportHTML()` but it seems a bit limited to what it can import from websites, from what I've seen it looks like you can only import from a site that has the data in a table or a list, but maybe there's something I'm overlooking?

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en

For example, let's say I'm trying to update my sheet based on the interest rates on this site:
https://celsius.network/rates/

I'm unable to grab the info because it's in a div stylized as a table.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `=IMPORTXML()` which support [xpath_query](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). In your use case, the query would be something like:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://celsius.network/rates/", "//div[@id='ETH']")
```

[Here's the spreadsheet that I've used](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15-FL17I9BBIS9wvhsxvUcQg8dfDYfmSV-Obssrsm7EA/) to make sure it's working. You can [make a copy by clicking here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15-FL17I9BBIS9wvhsxvUcQg8dfDYfmSV-Obssrsm7EA/copy).