# Google Sheets importxml() showing "Imported Content Empty"

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I'm would like to fetch some information(price, address, etc.) from this website:   https://www.realtor.ca/on/barrie/real-estate
using `importxml` function.
I'm getting a message "Imported Content Empty" instead the value.

Example:
`=importxml("https://www.realtor.ca/on/barrie/real-estate","//*[@id='SEOCardList']/ul/li[1]/div/a/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]")`

The solutions suggests in the other threads are not working for me, or maybe I missed other solutions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun/126329#126329).

Answer (score -1):

The website is not compatible with importxml, no way to fix it except going through a web proxy