# Importing data from Investors.com, getting #N/A (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, importhtml

I am attempting to pull from https://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-apple-inc-aapl.htm
I want to get the EPS Rating which is the 305th list item, which I found using
`var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"), function(x) { console.log(i++, x); });` in the console.

This is the importhtml i have used:
`=IMPORTHTML("https://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-apple-inc-aapl.htm","list",305)`

and the importxml i have used:
`=IMPORTXML("https://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-apple-inc-aapl.htm","/html/body/div[1]/div[9]/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/section/div/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[3]/li[2]")`
but all of them return "#N/A"

Error reads "Could not fetch url: [https://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-apple-inc-aapl.htm"](https://research.investors.com/stock-quotes/nasdaq-apple-inc-aapl.htm%22)

Am I approaching the IMPORT functions incorrectly? Or is the structure of this page not compatible with these functions? Any help is appreciated!

I should note that other domain prefixes import fine, such as "in.investors.com"
tested with `=IMPORTHTML("https://in.investing.com/equities/jagson-airlines-bo", "table",2)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the site you mention is behind a [cookie wall](https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/gdpr-no-cookie-consent-walls/), and thus cannot be accessed programmatically with any Google Sheets spreadsheet function.

See [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun/115665#115665)