# Google Sheets IMPORTXML Issue about Currencies

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, xpath

I've used these link and formula on Google Sheets to auto-update currency:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://tr.investing.com/currencies/gau-try";"//*[@id='last_last']")
```

However, it doesn't show anything for a while and I don't know how to update it.
I think something was changed "*[@id='last_last']" part, but I don't know well enough coding to find the new change and update it.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to [weabapps.se]. Have you already read [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://tr.investing.com/currencies/gau-try";"//span[@data-test='instrument-price-last']")
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

If you want to import the data from another sheet, the formula that you have given is for importing data from another sheet/URL.

If I understand your question you are looking to update the currency automatically, for that you can select the cell where you want to update the currency and then type ==GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EXAEXB") into it. You can replace "EXA" with currency code you want to update. Hope this helps if not you can comment so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: I think it only takes one = symbol

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. However, some currencies are not listed on Google Finance, like Gold in TRY. That's why I use Investing website. Could you please help me get the currency price from Investing page that I gave the link above? Thanks.