# How to extract contents of table in website into GOOGLESHEET?

Tags: google-sheets

I tried to extract content on this website https://www.asugsvsummit.com/gsv-edtech-150 to google sheet. I typed this code but it didn't work.  How can I do?

[image]

=IMPORTXML("https://www.asugsvsummit.com/gsv-edtech-150","//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[3]/section[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]")

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. You are trying to extract content from "https://www.asugsvsummit.com/gsv-edtech-150". But the formula you are using is accessing "https://celsius.network/rates". Is this a typo? Would you please edit your question to confirm the url that you are searching, describe EXACTLY what content you are trying to extract and provide a formula consistent with that url for that site. You might also provide snapshot to show the data you are trying extract.

Comment: Oops! I am sorry and I edit the link! Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: In this case, there is no magic bullet. Suggest you read: [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115665/196152)

Comment: Aha. I see~! Thank you so much! I will read it!

Comment: BTW, you have accepted an answer from @SkylarSeverson that is **NOT** an answer to your question. At its best it is simply "not an answer" but a referral to another person who might be able to resolve your problem; at worst it exists only to promote a product or service and does not disclose the author's affiliation (if any); that is, it is spam. In this case, I think it is simply "not an answer". You may wish to take the author's advice and seek help from that source, BUT it is not an answer in the terms of this forum that you should "accept".

Comment: I am beginner of this Stack of Flow and not familiar with UI of this plarform. 
I thought V sign means 'declare' ... Now I know that I made mistake. Thank you for letting me know. How can I cancel that I clicked the 'accept' button?

Comment: Hi, no worries. Looks like someone has taken care of it. And I hope we see you again soon.